AWS Beanstalk Missing elements in /var/app/current .Net app
I am working on a university projet and am trying to push my dotnet server online on a AWS beanstalk app through a code pipeline connected to my repository so I can run my website. However, the application requires a folder data/ containing more folders with txt and json files. My application is running but I can't figure out how to upload those.
I have added commands to the buildspec.yml in the root of my repository
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      dotnet: 8.0 # Specify your .NET version here
    commands:
      - echo Installing dependencies...

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Restore started on `date`
      - dotnet restore backend/DataCollector/DataCollector.csproj

  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - dotnet build backend/DataCollector/DataCollector.csproj
  
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Publish started on `date`
      - dotnet publish backend/DataCollector/DataCollector.csproj -c Release -o ./publish
      - echo "Copying data folder to publish directory if needed"
      - mkdir -p ./publish/data
      - cp -R backend/DataCollector/data/* ./publish/data
      - echo "Listing contents of publish directory for verification"
      - ls ./publish/data
      - ls ./publish

artifacts:
  files:
    - publish/**

I also created a .ebextensions/data_folder.config also in the root
files:
  "/var/app/current/data":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: webapp
    group: webapp

container_commands:
  copy_data_folder:
    command: "if [ -d /var/app/staging/publish/data ]; then cp -R /var/app/staging/publish/data /var/app/current/data; fi"
    leader_only: true

And I have adapted my .csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <EnableDefaultContentItems>false</EnableDefaultContentItems>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="8.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.9.0" />
    <Content Include="data\**\*" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

I tested the publish locally and it contains the data folder. I also tried online through ls commands in the yml and it seems to be there too during the build phase
Build started on Thu Oct 31 20:32:40 UTC 2024
[Container] 2024/10/31 20:32:40.181962 Running command dotnet build backend/DataCollector/DataCollector.csproj
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
/codebuild/output/src299735988/src/backend/DataCollector/Controllers/DataController.cs(93,17): warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference. [/codebuild/output/src299735988/src/backend/DataCollector/DataCollector.csproj]
  DataCollector -> /codebuild/output/src299735988/src/backend/DataCollector/bin/Debug/net8.0/DataCollector.dll
Build succeeded.
/codebuild/output/src299735988/src/backend/DataCollector/Controllers/DataController.cs(93,17): warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference. [/codebuild/output/src299735988/src/backend/DataCollector/DataCollector.csproj]
    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:13.71
[Container] 2024/10/31 20:32:54.224059 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2024/10/31 20:32:54.224081 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2024/10/31 20:32:54.261242 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2024/10/31 20:32:54.262709 Running command echo Publish started on `date`
Publish started on Thu Oct 31 20:32:54 UTC 2024
[Container] 2024/10/31 20:32:54.270629 Running command dotnet publish backend/DataCollector/DataCollector.csproj -c Release -o ./publish
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
/codebuild/output/src299735988/src/backend/DataCollector/Controllers/DataController.cs(93,17): warning CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference. [/codebuild/output/src299735988/src/backend/DataCollector/DataCollector.csproj]
  DataCollector -> /codebuild/output/src299735988/src/backend/DataCollector/bin/Release/net8.0/DataCollector.dll
  DataCollector -> /codebuild/output/src299735988/src/publish/
[Container] 2024/10/31 20:32:57.400301 Running command echo "Copying data folder to publish directory if needed"
Copying data folder to publish directory if needed
[Container] 2024/10/31 20:32:57.409300 Running command mkdir -p ./publish/data
[Container] 2024/10/31 20:32:57.427773 Running command cp -R backend/DataCollector/data/* ./publish/data
[Container] 2024/10/31 20:32:57.443373 Running command echo "Listing contents of publish directory for verification"
Listing contents of publish directory for verification
[Container] 2024/10/31 20:32:57.452385 Running command ls ./publish/data
bayes
gradient
[Container] 2024/10/31 20:32:57.528019 Running command ls ./publish
DataCollector
DataCollector.deps.json
DataCollector.dll
DataCollector.pdb
DataCollector.runtimeconfig.json
Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.dll
Microsoft.OpenApi.dll
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll
data
web.config

But I get a rollback during the Deploy phase of the pipeline, and when i check in EC2 console, I can't find the folder in my current app
[root@ip-172-31-91-55 current]# ls
DataCollector            DataCollector.dll  DataCollector.runtimeconfig.json  Microsoft.OpenApi.dll  Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll     Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll
DataCollector.deps.json  DataCollector.pdb  Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.dll  Procfile               Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll  web.config

Edit:
I found a solution which I don't really like because it is not an automated process, but I succeeded by directly uploading publish.zip on the button 'Upload and Deploy'. This isn't great since I manually need to do it at every change but at least it works
